# How to do android.intent.action.VIEW in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a pdf viewer app and I want to add functionality where someone clicks on pdf file in file manager then I want to show my app in the list of open with options.
I know we have to use method channels and android intents but does someone know how to do it?

like this:
[image]

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this plugin. Using this plugin, we can receive the data from other apps to our flutter app.

https://pub.dev/packages/receive_sharing_intent